# open and close div to show image when clicking text javascript

Tags: javascript, image, function

I'm using this javascript to open a div containing an image when clicking on a text
http://jsfiddle.net/BfMDL/1/

my script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image_trombi').hide();

    $('.titre').click(function() {
        $('.image_trombi').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        return false;        
    });
});
```

my html

```
<div><a href="#" class="titre">image 1</a><div class="image_trombi"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-200-200-9.jpg" class="trombi_anim"/></div>
<div><a href="#" class="titre">image 2</a><div class="image_trombi"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" class="trombi_anim"/></div>
<div><a href="#" class="titre">iamge 3</a><div class="image_trombi"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-c-200-200-5.jpg" class="trombi_anim"/></div>
```

It works perfectly, but I would like the div to close after clicking again on the link.

So, click on "image1", open image 1, and click again on "image1" close image 1...
and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use only `slideToggle()` as you are doing [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) you don't need to `slideUp()` that image container.

```
$('.titre').click(function() { 
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    return false;        
});
```

### Fiddle Demo

Comment: But what if you slidedown a particular image and click another image.The first image would be still slidedown.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple [demo](http://andrestorres.com.ar/junk/accordion.html) of an accordion effect that i made a year ago.

JS

```
(function() {

    var menu = $('#acordion'),
        contents = menu.find('.acordion-content').hide();

    menu.children('li').click( function() {
        contents.slideUp(200);
        $(this).children('.acordion-content:hidden').slideDown(200);
    });
})();
```

HTML

```
<ul id="acordion">
    <li>
    <div class="acordion-title">Cosa1</div>
    <img class="acordion-content" src="" />
</li>
<li>
    <div class="acordion-title">Cosa2</div>
    <img class="acordion-content" src="" />
    </li>
<li>
    <div class="acordion-title">Cosa3</div>
    <img class="acordion-content" src="" />
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrès, anyway I'll use an other solution